# How to access applications running in a docker containers inside docker?

Tags: docker, docker-network

I am having a weird scenario in my project.

I am running "Supervisor" application in one of docker container.

Using this supervisor I am running two "web applications" in docker containers and both are using one micro service; again installed in another docker container.

Now, I can able to access my application from "Supervisor's container". But obviously it is not accessible from my machine.

How can I able to access my applications "Web App1" or "Web App2" from my machine?

I have less knowledge related to docker networking.
Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Docker manages network traffic between "host machine" and containers. In this case you have many dockers on different layers. On each layer you have to expose the ports of the internal containers to the "docker host" on the next layer and so on.

This is a solution over ports:

So the "Supervisor" on `172.17.42.1` must expose the ports of all the internal containers `(172.17.0.2-4)` as its own ports. So for "Supervisor" you need a `-p` docker parameter for each port of all containers inside the "Supervisor".

Expose the network:

Configure the local machine to send any network packet `172.17.*.*` to `172.17.42.1`. Then configure `172.17.42.1` to send network packages for IPs `172.17.0.*` to its network adapter `Docker0` (default docker network adapter). The exact implementation is dependent on your distribution.

Another solution:

Skip your Supervisor container and use `docker-compose` to arrange and manage your internal containers.

Answer (score 0):

You can map ports of Web App1 and Web App2 to the host container and using the IP address and port you can access those containers from you machine. A better way to do this is to add hostname for your containers and maps ports so you don't have to remember the IP addresses since they are generated randomly on every time the container is recreated.